# How can I have text blink every second?

Tags: android

In my application I have displayed the time in the form of "hh:mm a". Now I want to blink the `:` for every second, how?

Comment: Implement Countdowntimer and scop of that alternatively change color of text

Comment: if answer, solve your problem click on "Right" mark

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
 TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText );

 Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
 anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
 anim.setStartOffset(20);
 anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
 anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
 myTextview.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

put `:` in a view inside `viewFlipper` , set blinking effect in `showNext()` and `showPrevious()` .set `autoStart= true` and `indeterminant=true` ;